# How to copy file in UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, copy

I use database in my UWP application. I want to peak a database file using FilePeaker and then copy it into application folder. But application refuses to copy file and exception "Access to the path [filePath] is denied" rises.

```
async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
{

    var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
    if (result != null)
    {
        if (result.FileName.EndsWith("db", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        { 
            string st = Path.Combine(App.APPFOLDER, result.FileName);
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(result.FullPath);
        try
        { f.CopyTo(st); }
        catch (Exception ex) { };       
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is the way to copy file in UWP?

Comment: what file path are you using?

Comment: Any file path gives one result. I select path by FilePicker, I set "d:\" [root of hard drive], and so one - the same result.

Comment: is the exception caused by the source file or the destination file?  What is the path contained in `App.APPFOLDER`?

Comment: Soruce file is the reason. Any selected file is denied.

Comment: public static string APPFOLDER = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options available; none of which are obvious based on your problem description. For example, a "database file" could be the underlying "physical" database file; which is not something one "copies".

With UWP, your options are addressed in "App-to-app communications"; with copy and paste; and drag and drop being the most obvious ones.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/